# How to QueryOver using correlated subqueries over an aggregate value?

Tags: nhibernate, queryover

I have the following domain mappings:

```
Person
------
int PersonId
IList<PersonDetails> Details;

PersonDetails
-------------
Person Owner (mapped by using the FK field, PersonId)
string Name
string Address
DateTime UpdateDate
```

translated to a similiar table structure:

```
Person
------
PersonId (int)
Birthday (date)

PersonDetails
-------------
PersonId (FK, integer)
Name (string)
Address (string)
UpdateDate (date)
```

How do i recreate the following SQL query using QueryOver?

```
SELECT * 
FROM Person p INNER JOIN Details d ON p.PersonId = d.PersonId 
WHERE d.UpdateDate = (SELECT MAX(UpdateDate) 
                      FROM   PersonDetails
                      WHERE  PersonId = p.PersonId);
```

i.e, select the latest PersonDetails for each Person.
I've seen examples, but neither of them related to a correlated subquery using an aggregae value...

Thanks,
Harel

Comment: I'm sorry, your tables relationship is OneToMany, correct?

Comment: Oh, sorry i forgot this detail - the mapping is indeed a one-to-many relationship, as Person can "own" many PersonDetails objects.

Comment: I'm sorry but I haven't found a solution for your query but...if you're using Fluent NHibernate to map your tables to your models and if your query on Person and PersonDetails ALWAYS uses SELECT MAX(UpdateDate) maybe I've an idea :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Hey, after sweating hard to find a solution, the following did the trick:

```
QueryOver.Of<Person>(() => personAlias)
     .Left.JoinAlias(p => p.Details, () => personDetailsAlias)
     .WithSubquery.WhereProperty(() => personDetailsAlias.UpdateDate).Eq(
            QueryOver.Of<PersonDetails>(() => maxPersonDetailsAlias)
                 .Where(ps => maxPersonDetailsAlias.Owner.Id == personAlias.Id)
                 .Select(Projections.Max<PersonDetails>(ps => ps.UpdateDate)))
                     .SelectList(resList => resList.Select(() => personAlias.Id).Select(() => personDetailsAlias.Id));
```

so the way for joining the correlated sub-query is by using an alias the 'outer' query.